# how to change autocomplete list user to select list user in Content Access?

Tags: users

I am currently using Content Access to set permission for node access right to specific user. My problem is that Content Access is using auto-complete to list all users, so are there any way to change that to select list widget so user can be easier to choose user instead of remember the user name?
Thanks,